# Copy more than one range of data from a closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba, external

What I am hoping to accomplish, is to copy select ranges of data from a closed workbook(Column D,H,Q and R) and paste them in the active workbook(Workbook with code below). The code below completes that but it displays "NULL" for values that it should not. For example, I am copying currencies (USD, CAD, GBP) which are all non-numbers and a portion of them display "NULL". One other objective is to have the ranges of data copied to be displayed like the closed workbook(in the order of the closed workbook) For example column A displays an entity and all the columns to the right show data for that entity.

```
Sub GetData_Example4()
Dim SaveDriveDir As String, MyPath As String
Dim FName As Variant

SaveDriveDir = CurDir
MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath    'or use "C:\Data"
ChDrive MyPath
ChDir MyPath
FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*")

If FName = False Then
    'do nothing
Else
    GetData FName, "Sheet1", "D1:D10000", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), 
False, False
    GetData FName, "Sheet1", "H1:H10000", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1"), 
False, False
    GetData FName, "Sheet1", "Q1:Q10000", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1"), 
False, False
    GetData FName, "Sheet1", "R1:R10000", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1"), 
False, False
End If

ChDrive SaveDriveDir
ChDir SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Below is the code for "GetData"

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As 
Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
    Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
    End If

   If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
       vbExclamation, "Error"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need me to explain anything in more detail.

Comment: Seems like you left out the `GetData` method?  That is kind of critical here.

Comment: @Tmacjoshua Tim is saying that in your post here you haven't shown us what `GetData` is - without posting that code, we can't help you.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added the code lines for GetData. Thank you!

Comment: "t will display an error the line after Else" - you need to be a little more specific about that.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when you see the error?

Comment: You have unqualified worksheet references - you should always qualify with a specific workbook object, or they will default to the active workbook

Comment: So change to (eg) - `GetData FName, "Sheet1", "D1:D10000", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), 
False, False`

Comment: The line highlighted is GetData FName, "Sheet1", "D1:D10000", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). I will try what you commented.

Comment: "subscript out of range" usually means you're trying to refer to a worksheet or workbook (or some element in an array or collection) which does not exist.  Does not seem like the issue is with GetData itself.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok I figured out the error. The data now copies over but it displays "NULL" for values that it should not. For example, I am copying currencies (USD, CAD, GBP) which are all non-numbers and a portion of them display "NULL". One other objective is to have the ranges of data copied to be displayed like the closed workbook(in the order of the closed workbook) For example column A displays an entity and all the columns to the right show data for that entity.

Comment: You'd have more control if you just open the source document and copy the content you want - using the query approach you're going to have to deal with more issues (as you're seeing with the NULL's, which are likely because there's mixed numeric/non-numeric data in your columns)

Comment: I agree but this is a weekly task and sometimes the user copying and pasting does it incorrectly. This would take away those errors. Do you have any suggesstions or ways around showing NULL? Thanks @TimWilliams

Comment: Not suggesting you do it manually - your would use a macro for the task.  All the user has to do it select the file.

Comment: That's was my goal with this code. Worked great other than NULL and it being out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this  -skipping the whole ADO thing:

```
Sub GetData_Example4()

    Dim SaveDriveDir As String, MyPath As String
    Dim FName As Variant, wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath    'or use "C:\Data"
    ChDrive MyPath
    ChDir MyPath
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*")

    If FName = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With Workbooks.Open(FName, ReadOnly:=True)
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D10000").Copy shtDest.Range("A1")
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1:H10000").Copy shtDest.Range("B1")
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q1:Q10000").Copy shtDest.Range("C1")
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1:R10000").Copy shtDest.Range("D1")
            .Close False '<< fixed
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

    ChDrive SaveDriveDir
    ChDir SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing thanks Tim. This is why I love this site. I think the code you wrote Close False is supposed to close the doc that opens. It's not a big deal or anything but is there something I can do to close the doc after that I copied the info from since it stays right now. I also have a question regarding bringing a userform into the same macro. Would you like me to ask another question or communicate it through here? @TimWilliams

Comment: Typo should have been `.Close False`  And best to post a new question if you have a new requirement

Comment: The workbook that I will be copying data from, has filters which will show the needed data depending on the person. Is there a way to adjust a filter of another workbook before copying it to the workbook with the code?

Comment: Yes - you'd do it the same way as you would adjust a filter in the current workbook - try recording a macro while making the adjustment if you're not sure where to start.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams the only thing is the variables in the filter could change. For example one month the file to extract could have the variables 3,4,12,15 in the filter, while the next month more could be added or some could be taken out. Do you have an idea how I would go about this. It shows an error for me with the macro because the filter asking to be filtered or hidden is not there.

Comment: Best to post a new question with what you have so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118811/when-automatically-adjusting-filters-ignore-filters-that-are-outside-the-scope that is what I have so far I'm close just have some errors